# wxPython control spacing

Tags: python, wxpython

I am writing up a rudimentary Intinerary Manager. Just a simple side-project to familiarize myself with using wxPython to create GUIs. This is my first attempt, and I can't seem to find any reference to this problem anywhere else.

My code is as follows:

```
import wx

class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(650, 1000))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        topLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, size = (-1, -1), label="Itinerary")

        vbox.Add(topLabel, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.listBox = wx.ListCtrl(panel, style = wx.LC_LIST)
        self.listBox.InsertColumn(0, "Test Column")
        self.listBox.Append(["This is an item"])
        self.listBox.Append(["This is another item"])

        vbox.Add(self.listBox, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Show(True)



app = wx.App(False)
frame = mainWindow(None, "Itinerary Manager")

app.MainLoop()
```

For some reason, this is resulting in an enormous margin between the StaticText element at the top and the ListCtrl below it. I've tried a few workarounds, including setting the parent of each to self, but that gives the same output. What can I do to make sure that these 2 controls have no (or very small) margins between one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling the `wx.StaticText` control to expand and take up half the application's width. You don't want that. So change the line 13 from this:

```
vbox.Add(topLabel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

to this:

```
vbox.Add(topLabel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
```

The number 1 tells wxPython what amount of proportion the widget should take up. Since both the static text and the listbox are both set to one, they each take up the exact same amount. Most of the time, a static text control shouldn't expand. Anyway, here's the full code:

```
import wx

class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(650, 1000))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        topLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, size = (-1, -1), label="Itinerary")

        vbox.Add(topLabel, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.listBox = wx.ListCtrl(panel, style = wx.LC_LIST)
        self.listBox.InsertColumn(0, "Test Column")
        self.listBox.Append(["This is an item"])
        self.listBox.Append(["This is another item"])

        vbox.Add(self.listBox, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)

        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Show(True)



app = wx.App(False)
frame = mainWindow(None, "Itinerary Manager")

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I see now. I was under the impression that setting the size superceded the wx.EXPAND tag. This makes more sense. Thank you for the answer.